# Why does this nested printf statement print "5 53"?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x=5;
    printf("%d", printf("%d %d",x,x));
}
```

How is the output `5 53` can someone explain ?
I tried myself and I think the answer should be `5 5 2`

Comment: Please don't use code samples in the question title; question titles should be in plain english

Comment: Why are you writing this code

Comment: @EdHeal was asked in an interview..

Comment: Why in the world would you think the answer is `"5 5 2"`??  Where did you get `"2"` from?  You should explain your (completely faulty) logic, and as soon as you do, you will probably realized the correct answer.

Comment: @user3086743: You could respect your fellow software developers by spelling out words correctly and adhering to the Q&A format of StackOverflow.  These are comments, and not answers; answers are in the section below.  BTW, I have more programming experience than you have years alive.  So I suggest you correct your attitude. Question downvoted because of attitude.

Comment: @abelenky "2" is reasonable, though incorrect, considering sibling function `scanf("%d %d",...)` would normally return 2.

Comment: 2 is reasonable ***IF*** and ***ONLY IF*** the poster provided an explanation for their logic.  Without explanation, it is just as reasonable to propose `"5 5 9"`

Comment: The answer at interview is that you are not sure and would consult the manual page

Comment: Ps it is ok at interview to say you don't know the answer. It is a strength

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you have more programming experience than years I've live .. wow make sure you write that in your CV it is a big achievement haha ! downvoted my ques? oh i'll never be able to find the answer now ahaha ! get a job mahn !

Comment: @abelenky I tried running the code in my mind and did not pay attention to the space so "2" came from the silly mistake, anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The return value of `printf` is the

> *number of characters transmitted to the output stream* or negative value if an output error or an encoding error (for string and character conversion specifiers) occurred

(from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), emphasis mine) and "5 5" are *three* characters (namely "five space five"). So the last number printed is 3.